# Как переименовать переменную?

Tags: javascript

Например, я создал `var lol = "lol123"`. Как изменить `lol` на `loltest1`?

Comment: Просто взять в коде и переименовать. А если при исполнении кода, то зачем вообще вам это нужно?

Comment: А как переименовать объект объекта? Например lolobject = {"lol123s":"testexample", "lolus123":"loled"} Я хочу чтобы "lol123s" был переименован в "examplelol".

Comment: Завязывайте вы с этим "лол"... И насчет объекта: а вам не кажется, что в вопросе вы совсем другое спросили, и, соответственно, ответы вам дали совсем не о том?

Comment: не знаю. А как объект объекта переименовать?

Comment: Завязывай лучше с этим вопросом? Зачем тебе переименовывать переменную? Создай копию с новым именем, а старую удали.

Answer (score 10):

Переименовать переменную нельзя, только присвоить новой переменной ее значение.

Answer (score 7):

Переименовать в JS нельзя. Но если нужно новое название, можно сделать так:

```
var lol = "lol123"

var loltest1 = lol;

alert( loltest1 );
```

Answer (score 6):

Вот пример как изменить ключ в объекте

```
var objlist = [{
    "lol" : "text",
    "wow" : "text"
}];

function renameProperty(obj, fromKey, toKey) {
    obj[toKey] = obj[fromKey];
    delete obj[fromKey];
}

objlist.forEach(obj => renameProperty(obj, 'lol', 'darova'));
```

Comment: а если возле obj точки есть? Например: obj.real

Answer (score 3):

Так как истинный вопрос, судя по комментариям, в том как переименовать свойство объекта, то:

Переименовать свойство объекта можно, создав в объекте свойство с новым именем и старым значением, после чего удалив старое свойство:

```js
var object = { "123s": "testexample", "us123": "ed" };
console.log(object);

object["example"] = object["123s"];
delete object["123s"];
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 3):

Использовать функцию `rename` :D
Вот сама функция, если вы о ней не знаете

```
function rename(oldName, newName) {
    window[newName] = window[oldName];
    delete window[oldName];
}
var lol = "lol123";

rename('lol', 'loltest1');

console.log(lol);
console.log(loltest1)
```

Comment: обычное создание новой переменной с присвоением ей значение старой. За имя функции вот тебе :)

Comment: @programmer403 верно))

Answer (score 2):

Переименовывать нигде нельзя. Ты можешь создать копию с другим именем, а старую переменную удалить.